# AppleScript to get the ordering index of open windows on the desktop

Tags: mac, applescript, automation

I am fairly new to AppleScript. I have been trying to find a way to get the order or index of all visible windows front to back regardless of application i.e. 1st is the frontmost on the Desktop then 2nd the window behind it, 3rd the window behind that and so on.

I can see how to access indexing properties within applications but I have not found any direct way to get the current order of all open windows. Is this information contained anywhere? Or is there a suitable workaround?

My ultimate goal is to make a script which takes a number of windows from the apps being used and arranges their bounds in the preferred configuration. This is to quickly organise the screen. Thank you for any pointers in the right direction you can offer!